# Routing doesn't work in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, web

I am new to the AngularJS and I was learning it through CodeSchool's video series. But now I am facing an error when I try to route through a click on an image. Kindly help me.

Here are my HTML and JavaScript files

```js
//app.js
/**
*  Module
*
* Description
*/
angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute'])
 .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.clicked="";
  $scope.numberofClicks=0;
  $scope.clickMe=function()
  {
    
   $scope.clicked="Image Clicked"; 
   $scope.numberofClicks+=1;
   alert("Image has been clicked");
  };
 }]);

 

//route.js

angular.module('myModule')
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {

 $routeProvider.
                when('/firstQuiz', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/firstpage.html'
                }).
                when('/secondQuiz', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/secondpage.html'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title>Testing For Image Click</title>
 <!--Order Matters-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/route.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
 
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <img class="img-rounded background-image" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="img/gameoft.jpg">
   <a href="#/firstQuiz"><img class="img-rounded play-image" src="img/something.svg"/></a>
  </div>


  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <img class="img-rounded background-image" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="img/gameoft.jpg">
   <a href="#/secondQuiz"><img class="img-rounded play-image" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="img/something.svg"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br/>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <img class="img-rounded background-image" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="img/gameoft.jpg">
   <img class="img-rounded play-image" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="img/something.svg">

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <img class="img-rounded background-image" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="img/gameoft.jpg">
   <img class="img-rounded play-image" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="img/something.svg">

  </div>
 </div>


 <div ng-view>
  

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

These are the two errors that I am facing:

> Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/nomod?p0=myModule angular.min.js:6:411

The other one is too long to paste it here.

Comment: what is the error your facing?.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include details of the error?

Comment: @RichardEverett:the other error is quite long.that's why I Just posted the first error

Comment: What version of angular are you using? in the new versions of AngularJs angular-route is in a separate library.

Comment: @SagiLevi:yes that's why I already added angular-route in a different script tag

Comment: try this `https://jsfiddle.net/SachinRK/q3p1ktvj/`

Comment: @Pranjal added an answer, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load the `route.js` before the app.js page.
and when you load the `route.js`, the module "MyModule" isn't known to `angular`. try to change the order of these 2 files.

Comment: @Bujutsu include ap.js before route.js, that is what he's saying

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `:` after `https`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
```

It should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
```

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aOw1G4HOImrjHOn0kwEW?p=preview)

Hope that solve your problem.

Comment: Angular route is not loading up. Great observation